# how to insert the quotient of 2 variable in a database and then echo it as a percentage

Tags: php, sql, database

```
$score = 50
$total = 500

mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE student_quiz SET `grade` = ".$score." out of ".$total."')
```

So currently This will store "50 out of 500" in the database but what i want it to do is to store the quotient of $score and $total so it should be "0.1" instead of "50 out of 500".

And how do i make it as percentage when i display it so that it will become "10%" when i echo the $grade instead of "0.1"
Currently this is how i fetch and display the grade.

```
$query1 = mysqli_query($conn,"select * from student_class_quiz where class_quiz_id = '$id' and student_id = '$session_id'")or die(mysqli_error());

    $row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($query1);
    $grade = $row1['grade'];
   <?php echo $grade; ?>
```

Comment: Why don't you store both values as integers? Then you can display `sprintf('%d%%', $row1['score'] / $row1['total']* 100)`. So it is 50/500 * 100 and a percent sign which is `10%`.

Answer (score -1):

Calculate the quotient with `$score/$total`.

```
$score = 50;
$total = 500;
$quotient = $score/$total;
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn,"UPDATE student_quiz SET `grade` = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $quotient);
$stmt->execute();
```

To show it as a percentage, multiply by 100.

```
<?php
$query1 = mysqli_prepare($conn,"select * from student_class_quiz where class_quiz_id = ? and student_id = ?") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
$query1->bind_param("ss", $id, $session_id);
$query1->execute();
$result = $query1->get_result();
$row1 = $result->fetch_assoc($query1);
$grade = $row1['grade'];
echo "Grade percentage is " . round($grade*100) . "%";
```